# Stored Procedure expected multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

Expecting duplicate row with different output in the last column.

Here's my Stored Procedure query

```
SELECT
    Name = SELECT ......
    Mobile = SELECT .....
    Title = SELECT .....
    Developer = (SELECT Description FROM ParameterDeveloper WHERE Id IN (SELECT WorkId FROM Company WHERE Id = Records.ApplicationId)
FROM Records
```

Here's my Records Table

| ApplicationId | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | Sky |
| 300 | Sam |
| 400 | Luke |

Here's my ParameterDeveloper Table

| Id | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | Oracle |
| 100 | Ibm |
| 200 | Salesforce |

Here's my Company Table

| Id | WorkId |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 100 |
| 200 | 200 |
| 300 | 300 |

Expected result -

| Name | Developer |
| --- | --- |
| Sky | Oracle |
| Sky | Ibm |

My Error is:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: The error is explicit, you are trying to assign multiple values to a single column. You need to alias your table names because as it stands you have columns present in multiple tables and you are not distinguishing them.

Comment: Your subquery returning multiple row try to add in your query `select top 1`

Comment: @jishansiddique adding top is not a good solution - OP needs to understand the logic of what they are selecting and ensure the where clause is correct.

Comment: If your records table has 3 rows, and you are selecting from it, how can your expected results only have 2rows?

Comment: Seems you want a join, not a sub-query.

Comment: Exactly... so that comment is more useful than suggesting top 1

Comment: For Records.ApplicationId=100 (for example), Company.WorkId=100 is retieived (1 row, ok so far); for this row, two rows are retrieved for ParameterDeveloper.Id=100 (Descriptions: Oracle, IBM); which one of these two do you want to assign to Developer? sql-server has no way of knowing (and it will not duplicate the rows from Records to accommodate; if you want rows to be duplicated for these matches, you should be using JOINs)

Comment: chill guys. Don't fight. Yeah. JOIN is my option too. im now trying it.

Comment: I tried using JOIN Query but now, im having duplicated rows
SKY | ORACLE
SKY | ORACLE
SKY | IBM
SKY | IBM

Comment: @Ariesthen you need to show us your query, because the answer below returns your desired results.

Comment: @dalek done ✅ I've removed the comment thank you for the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your data

```
CREATE TABLE Records (
   ApplicationId INTEGER  NOT NULL 
  ,Name          VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO Records
 (ApplicationId,Name) VALUES 
(100,'Sky'),
(300,'Sam'),
(400,'Luke');

CREATE TABLE ParameterDeveloper (
   Id          INTEGER  NOT NULL 
  ,Description VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO ParameterDeveloper 
(Id,Description) VALUES 
(100,'Oracle'),
(100,'Ibm'),
(200,'Salesforce');

CREATE TABLE Company (
   Id     INTEGER  NOT NULL 
  ,WorkId INTEGER  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO Company
(Id,WorkId) VALUES 
(100,100),
(200,200),
(300,300);
```

your query

```
select Name,Description 
from Records R
JOIN Company C
ON C.Id=R.ApplicationId
JOIN ParameterDeveloper P
ON P.Id=R.ApplicationId
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tKCWfkCB)

Comment: If i used join query - i got 4 rows

SKY ORCLE SKY ORCLE
SKY IBM SKY IBM

Comment: @Aries not with the sample data provided - you must have a more complex situation that you haven't fully explained.

Comment: @DaleK , i apologized. it is really hard to explain when coz english is not my first language. im gonna try the join query again :)

Comment: @DaleK, yeah. it works now. i just forgot the ParameterCompanyId = Record.ApplicationId